# Where can I find a host with stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, hosting, view

I have created a project that uses mysql stored procedures and views.

I have a lot of difficulties to find a hosting service that would support them.

Do you know where I can go?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any host that has MySQL 5.0 or more should support stored procedures and views. You might have trouble getting a salesperson that understands MySQL well enough to answer your questions though.

I know for certain that my basic, shared hosting plan at hostgator.com lets me have stored procedures and views.

Answer (score 0):

Depends a lot on your budget.  Amazon EC2 is a relatively cheap option compared to dedicated hosting but not as cheap as shared hosting packages.  But you do get the flexibility of your own MySql instance.

Have a look at http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1663

Answer (score 0):

you're not likely to find a shared host that lets you create procedures. you will likely need to get a dedicated hosting plan.

Answer (score 0):

A shared hosting package will be setup to not allow that by default, but after having your account activated, you can ask the tech support team to enable access to stored procedures and views.

Answer (score 0):

Host gator seems to support it